# align text inside li vertically

Tags: html, css

I have custom list item markers and when I displaying them text aligned in bottom . How to align it  vertically in the center . Display flex and align items doesn't help. Here you can check in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-sun-1yx9k

[image]

```
li {
        list-style-position: outside;
        list-style-image: url("/static/images/list.svg");
    }
```

Comment: The list-style properties give you rather little control over that, you’re better off using pseudo elements to insert these marker in the first place, then you have a lot more control about where/ how you position them.

Comment: Instead of using `list-style` properties, I would create a pseudo element to use as the bullets. Gives you far more control.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek I have attached sandbox link , Image , necessary css code. It just a simple list item . Why you devoted

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue not too long ago and solved it by using a `background-image` instead of `list-style-image` since you can't do much for alignment with those.

```
li {
        background-image: url(/static/images/list.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 50px;
    }
```

Comment: if you change the padding style with padding: 15px 0 15px 50px; it works like he wanted (i guess)

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a height to the li element e.g.

```
li {
  height: whateverValueYouWant;
  line-height: whateverValueYouPut;
}
```

So that it centers it vertically.